# Comparing two pandas dataframe to see the changes and list them out after grouping on three columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1 and df2 which gives the list of customers at different points of time. Each customer is in a District. Districts are grouped into Regions, which are grouped into Zones.
I am trying to create a table which shows the change in customer count by Zone/Region/District.
Teh output should be as the output below, with the following columns:

1. Zone
2. Region
3. District
4. Initial Count
5. Final Count
6. Transfer Out Count
7. Transfer In Count
8. New Customer Count
9. Leaver Count
10. Names of Transfer-Ins
11. Names of Transfer-Outs
12. Names of Leavers
13. Names of New Cusotmers

I am able to use groupby and concat to get a dataframe with the counts upto column 9 above. But how do I add the columns with names?

```
df1
  cust_name   cust_id town_id  Zone     Region   District
1 cxa          c1001    t001      A       A1        A1a
2 cxb          c1002    t002      A       A2        A2a
3 cxc          c1003    t001      A       A1        A1a
4 cxd          c1004    t003      B       B1        B1a 
5 cxe          c1006    t002      A       A2        A2b 
6 cxf          c1007    t002      A       A2        A2b

df2
  cust_name   cust_id town_id  Zone     Region   District
2 cxb          c1002    t002      A       A2        A2a
3 cxc          c1003    t001      A       A1        A1a
4 cxd          c1004    t003      A       A1        A1a 
5 cxe          c1006    t002      A       A2        A2a 
6 cxf          c1007    t002      C       C1        C1a


output
  Zone  Region  District Initial Count Final Count Transfer Out  Transfer In New Cust Leaver   NamesTransferIn  NamTransferOut    NamLeaver  NamNewCustomer 
   A      A1       A1a         2            2             0          1          0       1      cxd                                    cxa 
   A      A2       A2a         1            2             0          1                         cxe
   A      A2       A2b         2            0
   B      B1       B1a         1            0             1          0          0       0      transferOut: cxd
   C      C1       C1a         0            1             0          0          1       0              newCustomer:  cxf
```

Comment: Why is the `Transfer Out` number of `A2b` district empty? I found that `cxe` and `cxf` transferred out from `A2b` district. It should be 2, right?

Answer (score 0):

I process `NamesTransferIn` and `NamTransferOut` columns first.

Then I calculate `NamLeaver` and `NamNewCustomer` columns.

Here's the final code I created.

```
import pandas as pd

# Initialize data
data1 = {
    'cust_name': ['cxa', 'cxb', 'cxc', 'cxd', 'cxe', 'cxf'],
    'cust_id': ['c1001', 'c1002', 'c1003', 'c1004', 'c1006', 'c1007'],
    'town_id': ['t001', 't002', 't001', 't003', 't002', 't002'],
    'Zone': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],
    'Region': ['A1', 'A2', 'A1', 'B1', 'A2', 'A2'],
    'District': ['A1a', 'A2a', 'A1a', 'B1a', 'A2b', 'A2b']
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {
    'cust_name': ['cxb', 'cxc', 'cxd', 'cxe', 'cxf'],
    'cust_id': ['c1002', 'c1003', 'c1004', 'c1006', 'c1007'],
    'town_id': ['t002', 't001', 't003', 't002', 't002'],
    'Zone': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C'],
    'Region': ['A2', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'C1'],
    'District': ['A2a', 'A1a', 'A1a', 'A2a', 'C1a']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Merge df1 and df2 so that they become easier to compare
df_merged = df1.merge(df2, on='cust_name', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))

# Separate the customers into "In" and "Out" group
df_merged['Transfer'] = df_merged.apply(lambda x: 'In' if x['District_df1'] != x['District_df2'] else 'Out', axis=1)

# Process transfer_in and transfer_out
transfer_in = df_merged[df_merged['Transfer'] == 'In'][['Zone_df2', 'Region_df2', 'District_df2', 'cust_name']]
transfer_out = df_merged[df_merged['Transfer'] == 'In'][['Zone_df1', 'Region_df1', 'District_df1', 'cust_name']]

# Rename columns
transfer_in.rename(columns={'Zone_df2': 'Zone', 'Region_df2': 'Region', 'District_df2': 'District', 'cust_name': 'NamesTransferIn'}, inplace=True)
transfer_out.rename(columns={'Zone_df1': 'Zone', 'Region_df1': 'Region', 'District_df1': 'District', 'cust_name': 'NamTransferOut'}, inplace=True)

# Group transfer_in and transfer_out
transfer_in_grouped = transfer_in.groupby(['Zone', 'Region', 'District']).agg({'NamesTransferIn': lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()
transfer_out_grouped = transfer_out.groupby(['Zone', 'Region', 'District']).agg({'NamTransferOut': lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()

# Merge transfer_in_grouped and transfer_out_grouped
result = pd.merge(transfer_in_grouped, transfer_out_grouped, on=['Zone', 'Region', 'District'], how='outer').fillna('')

# Find customers that exist in df1 but not in df2
leavers = df1[~df1['cust_name'].isin(df2['cust_name'])][['cust_name', 'Zone', 'Region', 'District']]
leavers_grouped = leavers.groupby(['Zone', 'Region', 'District']).agg({'cust_name': lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index().rename(columns={'cust_name': 'NamLeaver'})

# Find customers that exist in df2 but not in df1
new_customers = df2[~df2['cust_name'].isin(df1['cust_name'])][['cust_name', 'Zone', 'Region', 'District']]
new_customers_grouped = new_customers.groupby(['Zone', 'Region', 'District']).agg({'cust_name': lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index().rename(columns={'cust_name': 'NamNewCustomer'})

# Append leavers and new customers to result
result = pd.merge(result, leavers_grouped, on=['Zone', 'Region', 'District'], how='left').fillna('')
result = pd.merge(result, new_customers_grouped, on=['Zone', 'Region', 'District'], how='left').fillna('')

print(result)
```

Here's the output of the above code.

```
  Zone Region District NamesTransferIn NamTransferOut NamLeaver NamNewCustomer
0    A     A1      A1a           [cxd]                    [cxa]               
1    A     A2      A2a           [cxe]                                        
2    C     C1      C1a           [cxf]                                        
3    A     A2      A2b                     [cxe, cxf]                         
4    B     B1      B1a                          [cxd]
```

Comment: thnak you very much Brian, this looks extremely promising. Let me check it out!

Comment: hey Brian, there is a corner case I am running against. say if there is a customer which has a Zone but no Region is assigned, or with a Zone and Region but the district is NaN, then it is not picking up those names. is there a solution for this?

Comment: What is the expected output when a `Region` or a `District` is `NaN`? Can you add an example in the question?